# Android RSS XmlPullParser: cannot write to String array or ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, rss, xmlpullparser

rather new to programming, trying to solve this for several days, read multiple tutorials and questions here, still cannot make this work.

Task - read wordpress RSS feed into ListView.
Problem - i've managed to successfully count number or titles, or get the last one. When trying to write all titles to array or array list, i fail. Simple String array gives endless cycle, String ArrayList gives empty values.

Here's the code I'm trying to write to ArrayList. Removed connection part, which seems to be working.

```
public class HandleXML{
private String title = "title";
ArrayList<String> listAdapterValues = new ArrayList<String>();

public ArrayList<String> parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
    int event;
    String text = null;
    ArrayList<String> allTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    .....
    try {
        event = myParser.getEventType();

        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String name = myParser.getName();

            switch (event) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                text = myParser.getText();
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                if (name.equals("title")) {
                    title = text;
                    allTitles.add(title);
                }

                else if (name.equals("link")) {
                }

                else if (name.equals("pubDate")) {
                }
                break;
            }

            event = myParser.next();

        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return allTitles;
}
....

public class NewsPage extends Activity {
ArrayList<String> allTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
....
    obj = new HandleXML(finalUrl);
    allTitles = obj.fetchXML();
....
```

I'm not getting any errors on logcat, seems i'm doing something wrong but don't understand what is it.

Any help would be appreciated,
thank you!